# What does it mean "plays with data, words and music"?

Tags: american-english

One of my friend wrote on her profile,
"plays with data, words and music."
She is a data scientist. Is this also wordplay?

Comment: Please provide full context. Apparently, the words are used literally, and no more.

Comment: Here, "plays with" probably just means "tinkers with," "enjoys working with," or "finds pleasure in."

Answer (score 0):

Well, wordplay is a pun; playing music is a pun; these look intentional, so I'd say arguably yes. I don't see any obvious pun for data, however.